# Redhat Enterprise Linux 4 / CentOS 4 Anaconda Process Crash During Install in Virtual Machine

Tags: centos, rhel, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

On a Windows 10 host with Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz I'm trying to setup a virtual machine installation of Redhat Enterprise Linux 4 to test scenarios for migration project to a modern version.

However within VMWare Workstation 16, Hyper-V and Oracle VM Virtual Box 6.1 I am unable to complete the install. Process anaconda terminates, call trace references vsnprintf, seq_printf, inode_has_perm, show_cpuinfo, seq_read, vfs_read and system_class.

I've tried text installation, noapic, noprobe options during install but so far have same issue.

Any suggestions if there is config change or install options that can allow this to complete?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CentOS-4.8-x86_64-binDVD.iso` works just fine here albeit I had to add  `nmi_watchdog=0` as a kernel boot argument to be able to boot.

I'm using VirtualBox 6.1.26 and created the configuration (RAM: 2GB, Disk: 8GB) using a CentOS 4 moniker.

Comment: The DVD version that you mention was the only one I could get working with nmi watchdog option. Excellent. I guess it must have some patch for the issue I was facing.